# Which options are there in combination with the TeX Gyre Fonts using pdflatex?

Tags: fonts, pdftex

Everything started with me wanting to use the TeX Gyre Heros font in a document. I needed the font scaled down a little bit, so I issued the command `\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{tgheros}` which threw an error. I've previously used the `scaled`-option with the `helvet`-package, so it took me a while to realize my error. After some googling I’ve found out that I needed to use the option `[scale=0.95]` without the `d`. Next I was looking for a way to use old-style figures which I also couldn't find. I am not even sure, there is such an option.

This has led me to my question: Is there a list or document describing the possible options I can use in combination with a font? While primarily interested in the TeX Gyre fonts, I am also interested in all the other fonts that could be used in combination with pdflatex. I realize that I can look this up in the documentation to the respective font-package. Yet not every documentation lists the available options.

My first address concerning fonts and (pdf)LaTeX is usually [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/). Yet, it only states how to load the fonts with the default options (at least I think these are the default options):

```
\usepackage[default,regular,black]{sourceserifpro}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Ideally **The LaTeX Font Catalogue** would also list the available options, so one doesn't have to read through the documentation of every font that's in the shortlist of fonts for the document. This would be immensely helpful since for example the package `sourceserifpro` alone supports the following options (from the [README.md](https://ctan.org/pkg/sourceserifpro) on CTAN):

```
oldstyle, osf:     use old style numbers.
lining, nf:        use lining numbers.
tabular:           use fixed-width numbers.
proportional:      use normal numbers.
black:             \bfseries is black.
semibold:          \bfseries is semibold.
bold:              \bfseries is bold.
light:             \mdseries is light.
extralight:        \mdseries is extra light.
regular:           \mdseries is regular.
scale, scaled:     set scaling for the font, eg: scale=.5
default:           Source Serif Pro is set as default font family.
normdefault:       Source Serif Pro is not set as roman (serif) family.
type1, t1:         override detection and load the Type1 font family.
opentype, otf:     override detection and load the OpenType font family.
```

Is there something similar for the TeX Gyre fonts and where can I find it?

Comment: the options are not (directly) related to the font, they are latex package options specific to a package. Normally you'd get the package documentation via `texdoc tgheros` although the latex package documentation is rather minimal in that case

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you. If I issue the command you've provided, I get `README-TeX-Gyre-Adventor.txt`. The option `scale` isn't even mentioned there. Am I correct to assume that the only way to gather information in that case is looking through the source code?

Comment: yes seems that way.